# Unity make an Expandable Scroll List (adding elements)

Tags: unity, gui, unity-ui

I am trying to make a scrollable list with premade elements that you can add using a button.
The problem is that the list's `Content` element needs to be exapanded as the list gets larger, and it's not made automatically.

If I expand the size of the list, it "works", more or less, because the list keeps expanded to a limited size, even if the list have only one element (for example), the list is scrollable until the maximum. And I don't want that result. I want to have the list as less expanded as possible, so it is only expanded until all elements are visible.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See my answer here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/175483/unity-adding-objects-through-script-to-scrollview-setparent-objects-overlap/197097#197097) regarding adding elements to a Scrollview and having the content area expand automatically.

Comment: If the same answer applies to both questions, it probably means that both questions are equivalent. Instead of answering and linking to another answer, you should vote to close the question as a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: didn't know I could do that <blush>

Comment: No worries; your votes are not yet registered on the question, given the amount of reputation you have, but the question has been added to the appropriate review queue so that other users with enough rep can take a look at it.

Comment: So, @Vaillancourt, do I need to remove the question or something?

Comment: IMO this question should remain for searchability purposes, even if marked as duplicate, as the other question was framed quite differently,  although the answer is ultimately the same.

Comment: @GospelBG No, no need to remove it, duplicate questions remain on the site and act as a sign post, as Acme Nerd Games says.